# Optimising Routing and React lazy loading for App with 2 sections on the landing page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-lazy-load

I have an app that has 2 sections on the landing page namely Entrance1 and Entrance2. I want to design my approutes and lazy-loading in such a way that when the user clicks on Entrance1 only routes related to Entrance1 and component needed inside Entrance1 should be loaded in the bundle (React-lazy and suspense. Not using webpack here). 50% of The routes and components inside Entrance1 and Entrance2 are duplicate.

I have a sandbox in which I have all routes belonging to Entrance1 and Entrance2 lying in one Approute. I have added minimal routes and components in the sandbox for brevity. But my apps have 25 routes belonging to Entrance1 and most of the same routes being used for Entrance2 (with the url pointing to /entrance2/comp1 instead of /entrance1/comp1) which I feel is not a good design. Also, it will make the bundle unnecessarily heavy to load.

how to get this working?

[Unoptimized way of Creating an app](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-merkle-jvtf0?file=/src/index.js)

Used React.lazy to break down the App in small bundles based on Routing Link

[Optimised Routing And Bundling](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-pascal-nrb59?file=/src/index.js)

1. Initially, the bundler post npm run build was showing 4 bundles as following:-

   Creating an optimized production build...
   Compiled successfully.

   ```
   File sizes after gzip:

     47.81 KB  build/static/js/2.19e3299d.chunk.js
     1.13 KB   build/static/js/main.7da2e471.chunk.js
     787 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.07a021b3.js
     746 B     build/static/css/main.870850a4.chunk.css
   ```
2. Post Optmization:-
   Creating an optimized production build...
   Compiled successfully.

   ```
   File sizes after gzip:

   47.81 KB (+2 B)  build/static/js/2.55b47d25.chunk.js
   1.21 KB (+91 B)  build/static/js/main.53ee5ec1.chunk.js
   1.2 KB (+442 B)  build/static/js/runtime-main.eace4f45.js
   746 B            build/static/css/main.870850a4.chunk.css
   290 B            build/static/js/4.9c560333.chunk.js
   288 B            build/static/js/3.cba0f305.chunk.js
   256 B            build/static/js/5.7e6af1ad.chunk.js
   ```

Comment: For starters, I would replace all those static routes with a dynamic route like `/:entrance/:comp` and load the data/components based on the paramaters

Comment: Ok. I made the routing optimized by creating a state variable from url and propogating that to other child components using Context. Now have fewer routes in the Approutes.js file.                                                          https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-pascal-nrb59?file=/src/index.js